# Reference Request for Combinatorial Game Theory

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Some time ago I found a paper, written I believe by Conway, in which the author describes different operations we may perform on combinatorial partizan games and how these operations can be used in order to endow games with a partial order.

For example, the most classical operation is the sum $G+H$ of games $G$ and $H$ in which the players play by choosing a component each time and playing a legal move in that component. Then we may say that a game $G$ is better $H$ for the left player if any time $L$ can win on $H+X$ she can also win on $G+X$ and we write $G\geq H$ (I'm simplifying a bit).

This paper predates ONAG (1976) and (then) also Winning Ways. I found this paper iteresting because it justifies a bit more why we define the classical partial order on games like we do and also considers what happens if we use different operations (for example one may require the players to play in both components each time).

Any help is really appreciated (and I will download interesting papers at once in the future).

Comment: How sure are you that it was Conway's paper, and how sure are you that it preceded ONAG? https://scholia.toolforge.org/author/Q268961 suggests that it wasn't both of those, at least.

Comment: Ahi! No, I'm not entirely sure that it's Conway's, and if it isn't there I suppose I must be mistaken (however that doesn't seem to be the complete list of Conway's publications).

Comment: Are there _any_ combinatorial game theory papers that predate ONAG? I thought ONAG was the foundational work of the theory.

Comment: Perhaps you were aware, but ONAG chapter 14 (2nd ed) discusses this exactly this topic, but only for impartial games.

Comment: Indeed, I'm aware, however that is not quite what I'm looking for. He doesn't start from operations on games to define an order and he doesn't concern himself about the properties of class of all games modulo the equivalence (obtained from such order).